# Multiple dataset for Bar chart in spss

Tags: graph, bar-chart, spss

I have 3 datasets of say group `A, B and C.` The sets represent different class of students whose ages are arranged as follows:

```
Ages

A={30,56,18, 25},

B={45,14,0,26},

C={26,79,58,16}
```

I was able to arrange the data in spss in the `rage 0-20, 21-40, 41-60, 61-80`.

I am having difficulty on how to plot these information in one bar chart,I'm newbie to `spss`.

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add an identification for the source group, then combine the files and then you can chart them:

```
dataset activate A.
string src (a10).
compute src="A".
dataset activate B.
string src (a10).
compute src="B".
dataset activate C.
string src (a10).
compute src="C".

add files /file=A /file=B /file=C.
exe.
dataset name ALL3.

* now you can chart away...
```